# 301 redirect to same domain name without changing the url

Tags: url, redirect, dns

I'm using 301 redirect to redirect my main index page to a different page under the same domain name.

*e.g. from **www.abc.com** to **www.abc.com/blog***

The problem is that I want the displayed url to remain the same as **www.abc.com** instead of **www.abc.com/blog** , but the page loaded is still my blog page.

Is that possible using 301 redirect? or is there a better solution?

Comment: 301 redirect is telling the browser to move to a new url. If you want the URL to stay the same try using a Mod Redirect value assuming your using apache.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file and place this in the root of your website:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://www.abc.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.abc.com/blog$1 [P]
</IfModule>
```